# how to trigger UI refresh when removing attendee with google calendar api

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-python-api

When removing an attendee via the patch method: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch the attendee's calendar view in the browser does not refresh showing they're no longer invited to the meeting.  How does one trigger a UI refresh so that the meeting is removed from their calendar in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying a lot of things to get it to work I think the solution is:

1. delete (https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete) the event from the attendee's calendar.  This will eventually mark the attendee as "declined" in the organizer's view of the event.
2. After this happens you can now remove the attendee from the organizer's calendar.

If you don't wait for the responseStatus to propagate to the organizer's calendar the UI refresh is strangely cancelled.  I have an open support case about this and will update if I'm provided any more information.

Comment: actually doing this ends up not being desirable because then the organizer gets a attendee declined email notification. :(